# crash on reading/writing from socket in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, crash

I have created a socket connection and it works fine. But sometimes it does crash if we run the app for the long time like 10 hrs or more. Here is part of crashylitcs log where I get crash at function - readMyData of class MyProxy.

```
#12. Crashed: MyProxy readMyData
0  MyMobile                   0x10489b768 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 5339242702
1  MyMobile                   0x10489bb50 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4108206691
2  MyMobile                   0x10488b3c8 CLSHandler + 3209137329
3  MyMobile                   0x104899d6c __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4506196141
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x19cbef184 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x19cbd2dc8 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 57
6  MyMobile                   0x1048997d8 CLSExceptionRecord + 42219194112
7  MyMobile                   0x1048992bc CLSTerminateHandler() + 4229193413
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x19ccef304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 15
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x19cceec58 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 31
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x19cceec18 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 112
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x19cce1f14 operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) + 91
12 PILFramework                   0x106bb2d8c -[EasySocketClient readBytesFromSocket:totalBytesToRead:forError:] + 142
13 PILFramework                   0x106bca068 -[MyProxy readMyData:] + 53274
14 Foundation                     0x19d30b09c __NSThread__start__ + 741
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19cc3dd8c _pthread_start + 155
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19cc4176c thread_start + 9
```

readMyData() creates a socket connection and does reading of data.

From above crash log - I see 
" **_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 57**" does it means reading/writing operation failing ?? or Any other root cause of crash.